# Facing issue while calling @viewchild in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

Hi guys i'm working with angular and want to call @viewChild in ts file but facing an error "Decorators are not valid here." cant find any specific solution for my problem

I have tried many links regarding this problem including angular documentation, stackoverflow, youtube but not able to find any appropriate solution to my problem

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload-card-details',
    templateUrl: './upload-card-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-card-details.component.css']
})
export class UploadCardDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(draganddropimage)
    constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}
    }

HTML:Code
<div class="modal fade custom-modal-setting" id="drag-and-drop-image" #draganddropimage tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Angular 8, you need to add `{ static: true }` in ViewChild

Try like this:

```
@ViewChild('draganddropimage', { static: true }) dragDropImageRef: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable and add the decorator to it :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload-card-details',
    templateUrl: './upload-card-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-card-details.component.css']
})
export class UploadCardDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('draganddropimage')
    private draganddropimage: ElementRef; 

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mustapha thanks alot for reply but still its not working error im getting is
**error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but  got 1.**

Comment: I edited the answer. you must put the name of the viewChild as string `@ViewChild('draganddropimage')`

Comment: If you're using Angular 8 you need to add  { static: true }
Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473899/error-ts2554-expected-2-arguments-but-got-1-with-viewchild

Answer (score 0):

I think you decorate constructor, try to set a name for @ViewChild(draganddropimage) draganddropimage

Answer (score 0):

You need to import ElementRef and then use this snippet to get your template reference using ViewChild :

```
@ViewChild('draganddropimage') dragDropImageRef: ElementRef;
```

Comment: Hi ilyas thanks for the reply but still not working getting
**error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but  got 1.**

Answer (score 0):

Just fighting with the same problem.
You need to put something between the decorator and the constructor:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(SomeChildComponent, { static: true })

  someVariable: SomeChildComponent; // this row is the magic (otherwise you decorate the constructor)

  constructor() {}
```